# Why does GHC only warn on partial implemented classes, and not error?

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass

I think the title is already self explanatory, but here's an example anyway to show my point:

```
class Foo a where
    someFunction :: a -> a -> Bool

instance Foo Bool
```

When I compile this the compiler gives a warning:

```
Warning:
    No explicit method or default declaration for `someFunction'
    in the instance declaration for `Foo Bool'
```

Calling the function will now result in a runtime error. Why is this a warning, and not a compile-time error? And is there any way to make this a compile-time error instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [GHC documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.3/docs/html/users_guide/options-sanity.html) provides an example where a warning is sufficient:

> `-fwarn-missing-methods`:
>
> This option is on by default, and warns you whenever an instance declaration is missing one or more methods, and the corresponding class declaration has no default declaration for them.
>
> The warning is suppressed if the method name begins with an underscore. 
>   Here's an example where this is useful:
>
> ```
> class C a where
>   _simpleFn :: a -> String
>   complexFn :: a -> a -> String
>   complexFn x y = ... _simpleFn ...
> ```
>
> The idea is that: (a) users of the class will only call `complexFn`; never `_simpleFn`; and (b) instance declarations can define either `complexFn` or `_simpleFn`.
>
> The `MINIMAL` pragma can be used to change which combination of methods will be required for instances of a particular class. See [Section 7.20.5, “MINIMAL pragma”.](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.3/docs/html/users_guide/pragmas.html#minimal-pragma)

That's the reason missing methods don't result in an error, but a warning. If you want to make warnings fatal, use `-Werror`. Since there is no `-ferr-missing-methods`, `-Werror` is the only way to make `-fwarn-missing-methods` a compiler error.

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient in the above example to properly specify the MINIMAL pragma to fix a warning/error? I.e. in the above example adding `{-# MINIMAL _simpleFn | complexFn #-}` would make the compiler happy as well, and thus still not give a reason for missing methods to give a warning instead of an error.

Comment: @Tiddo: The real reason is probably a historic one. That being said, one could patch [`warnMissingMethodOrAT`](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/33cfa5ff9db4e7886b3e7c2eed5ac1c75436bc4c/compiler/typecheck/TcInstDcls.hs#L1614-L1622) to create your desired behaviour. You could file an issue/feature request.